# Show listView with custom list adapter inside Fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-fragments

I am facing problem to show custom `listView` inside `Fragment` with `Tabbed Activity`.
Here is my java and xml files

**Section2Fragment.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class Section2Fragment extends Fragment {

   public Section2Fragment() {
   }

   ListView list;

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section2, container, false);

       Log.d(getFragmentManager().toString(), "Fragment Section 2");
       final String[] itemname = {
            "Safari",
            "Camera",
            "Global",
            "FireFox",
            "UC Browser",
            "Android Folder",
            "VLC Player",
            "Cold War"
       };

       Integer[] imgid = {
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
       };

       CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), itemname, imgid);
       list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.section2listView);
       list.setAdapter(adapter);

       list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               String Slecteditem = itemname[+position];
               Toast.makeText(getActivity(), Slecteditem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           }
       });
       return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section2, container, false);

    }
}
```

**CustomListAdapter.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] itemname;
    private final Integer[] imgid;

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, String[] itemname, Integer[] imgid) {
        super(context, R.layout.listview_item, itemname);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.context = context;
        this.itemname = itemname;
        this.imgid = imgid;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null, true);

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
        extratxt.setText("Description " + itemname[position]);
        return rowView;

    }
}
```

**fragment_section2.xml**

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#ff8720"
        android:id="@+id/section2container">
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/section2listView">

        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**listview_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#d7d7d7"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textColor="#33CC33" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#2c7bff"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My question is why the list items are not appearing on screen?
What should I have to do to solve the problem?

Comment: try it after setting  `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to ListView instead of `wrap_content`

Comment: nothing happened...!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your onCreateView. You inflate a layout using

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section2, container, false);
```

get a reference to the listview and instead of returning this inflated layout you return a new inflated layout.

Replace your

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section2, container, false);
```

with

```
return view;
```

in your `onCreateView()`.